# How to make monkeyrunner simulate a drag following a custom path on the android screen?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

The MonkeyDevice.drag currently can takes only 2 sets of co-ordinates which means I can move from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). Is there a way I could make the monkey runner simulate a drag from (x1,y1) to (x3,y3) and then to (x2,y2) without breaking the same drag function?

Answer (score 0):

Monkeyrunner is kind of deprecated.

You can use uiautomator instead. More details can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

This tool has a method for what you seek, a custom swipe using an array of points (x, y coordinates). More on that here:

[http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#swipe(android.graphics.Point[], int)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#swipe(android.graphics.Point[],%20int))

Answer (score 0):

I would use **Get/Send Event**.

Get an event, e.g. touch screen:

1. issue command: adb shell getevent | grep event2 > CaptureEvent.txt
2. do the touchscreen activity
3. stop the recording with CTRL+C

Convert the event:

4. e.g.: /dev/input/event1 3 47 0

Send an event:

5. issue commands, e.g.: adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 47 0